# When to Open/Close Connection with Node-Postgres and Serverless

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, serverless, node-postgres

I'm migrating from AWS Aurora PG to Heroku PG and I'm currently refactoring my queries. Using the `Node-Postgres` library in my Serverless Framework API, I now have to manage opening and closing the connection, something I didn't have to do with the AWS-SDK.

I am following [this](https://mattwelke.com/2019/01/06/free-tier-managed-sql-with-aws-lambda-and-heroku-postgres.html) article to setup my queries. Taken from the article:

```
let pgPool;

const setupPgPool = () => {
  // pgConfig is the host/user/password/database object
  pgPool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig);
};

module.exports.hello = async () => {
  if (!pgPool) {
    // "Cold start". Get Heroku Postgres creds and create connection pool.
    await setupPgPool();
  }
  // Else, backing container "warm". Use existing connection pool.

  try {
    const result = await pgPool.query('SELECT now()');

    // Response body must be JSON.
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        output: {
          currTimePg: result.rows[0].now,
        },
      }),
    };
  } catch (e) {
    // Return error message in response body for easy debugging.
    // INSECURE - CHANGE FOR PROD
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        error: e.message,
      }),
    };
  }
};
```

I'm trying to solve the issue of *where* to put the `pgPool`. My folder structure is like so:

```
src/
  controllers/
    auth/
      createUser.js
  models/
    authModel.js
    userModel.js
```

To dumb down my create `createUser` handler let's say it looks like this:

```
module.exports = (App) => {
  App.controllers.createAuth = async (event, context, cb) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
    const { email, password } = body

    try {

      const hash = createHash(password)
        
      // Auth is a class that contains all my auth table read/write functions to the db
      const Auth = new App.Auth()
      const authRecordId = await Auth.createAuth(email, hash)

      // User is a class that contains all my user table read/write functions to the db
      const User = new App.User()
      await User.createUser(authRecordId)

      const token = createToken(authRecordId)

      return cb(null, utils.res(200, { token }))

    } catch (error) {
      return cb(null, utils.res(500, { message: 'There was an error. Please try again' } ))
    }
  }
}
```

Inside my `authModel` I have:

```
let pgPool

const setupPgPool = () => {
  // pgConfig is the host/user/password/database object
  pgPool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig)
}

Auth.prototype.createAuth = async (email, hash) => {
  const sql = `
    INSERT INTO auth (email, hash)
    VALUES (lower($1), $2)
    RETURNING id;
  `
  const values = [ email, hash ]

  try {
    if (!pgPool) {
      await setupPgPool()
    }

    const { rows } = await pgPool.query(sql, values)
    await pgPool.end()
    return rows[0].id
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

The `userModal` query looks very similar (setup pgPool, run query, end connection, return data). The issue is `pgPool` never exists and I always need to `await` it before running the query. I also need to run `await pgPool.end()` otherwise my queries will hang. Is this the best practice, as the article suggests, in a Serverless Framework API?

Lastly, should I instead open the connection my handler and pass `pgPool` as an argument to my models? That way if I have to make more than one query to my database I don't have to `await setupPgPool` every time I want to read/write from the database?

**EDIT:** I was refactoring my first handler as I was writing this. After implementing what I used in the post, I am now running into this error: `Cannot use a pool after calling end on the pool`. Seems to be because I am closing the connection.

**EDIT 2:** Commented out the `await pgPool.end()` lines and now my calls hang again.. not really sure what to do..

Comment: a) The pool should be shared between all controllers. It should go inside a */services* directory or something

Comment: b) You'll want to use transactions and one client per request, not fire every individual query against the pool (on an arbitrary client). See https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions

Comment: c) You should use a helper function to inject a client into each controller. The helper function should acquire the client, run the controller, and `finally` release the client back to the pool

Comment: d) Depending on how you deploy your "serverless" API (lambdas? how do they scale? etc), you'll need to `end()` the pool when the container/process/etc is shut down, e.g. on a `process` signal. And you should configure the pool size accordingly to the scaling behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi sifting through your responses now (thank you a ton). I'm just a FE engineer faking my way into the BE world. I'm not sure about scaling at all, haven't made it that far with Heroku. Plus I'm not sure they offer insight into all of that? I saw how to create readers/writes on AWS RDS but moved off of Aurora due to really bad cold starts.

Comment: @Bergi As far as deploying, I'm using the Serverless Framework. I just run `serverless deploy`. I have not dabbled too much into performance (outside of trying to reduce cold starts) because I'm just trying to standup the app to play around with it on Heroku first.

Comment: AWS lambdas have the unfortunate (unusual for a node.js server) behaviour of never passing multiple requests to the same lambda process concurrently, rather spinning up separate lambda processes for concurrent requests (and later reusing them). For this, a connection pool max size of `1` would suffice as one nodejs process never needs to use two separate postgres clients. Acquiring more for some reason would be rather inefficient. (*Disclaimer* - this might have changed since I last researched the topic). But this is probably not very relevant until you really need to scale up…

Comment: @Bergi sorry, never mind about my last message if you saw it. I was misunderstanding transactions

Comment: @Bergi what do you do if you return out of the transaction because of an error/issue. My authUser handler will: get auth record, compared password hashes, get user record, return to client. How do you stop in the middle of the transaction and use the lambda callback? Example: User sends up a user/email combo. I get auth record by email and it exists. I check the password hash from auth record against the password hash provided and they don't match. I want to return out of this transaction and I need to use the lambda callback function and send back an error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253012/discussion-between-user2465134-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by the following:

- I started using "serverless-postgres" instead of "pg-node"
- But, I think this is the real reason, **I STOPPED USING THE CALLBACK PARAMETER**

I was going insane wondering how this was working for everyone else but me.

1. Started an entire new sls project and got it to return "hello"
2. Installed `serverless-postgres`, connected to my database but still return hello without any errors
3. Run this code:

```
  await client.connect();
  const result = await client.query(`SELECT 1+1 AS result`);
  await client.clean();
  return {
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: result.rows[0] }),
    statusCode: 200
  }
```

4. Tried to run that code on my project. Didn't work.
5. Compared my handler to this new projects handler and realized they just return instead of using the third parameter, `callback`.

Not sure when Serverless did away with `callback` and just returned (I guess I haven't been keeping up with the latest) but wrapping with `callback` was causing issues. Simply returning and removing callback fixed everything.

If you are having issues too I recommend you follow what I did. Get an external version of the basics working and try to slowly integrate it into your app.